# How to do an Index Match Formula with multiple criteria ? ( Having issues)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

sheet2
[image]

WorkSheet
[image]

The formula isn't pulling any value in return

'=IFERROR((INDEX((Sheet2!$A:$K,MATCH(Worksheet!XFD5,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Worksheet!E2,Sheet2!$H$1:$K$1,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!$H:$K,MATCH(Worksheet!E2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Worksheet!E2,Sheet2!$H$1:$K$1,0)))

Summary:

I'm attempting to pull the number for a specific color in Worksheet 1 (Row H) based on the criteria in Sheet2 in columns H:K.

Comment: Split it into sections like match() and check that result then does index() return a value using the result of match etc? Check each step logically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following method to extract value based on your data, it work perfectly, simply adjust the range based on your sheet will do:

```
=INDEX(H:K,MATCH(M2,A:A,0),MATCH(P2,$H$1:$K$1,0))
```

[image]